# Can someone please help me with this Validation rule! Sorry I am new to SF

Tags: validation-rule

Can someone please explain this validation rule and under what scenario it will throw error while saving/updating record

Also $Profile.Name checks the user's profile who is saving/updating record?

Please ignore the syntax error as it is working fine in the org

```
AND
(
OR(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Status)) =‘Esc’,PRIORVALUE(Status)) =‘Pending’)),

NOT(ISNEW()),

OR($Profile.name=‘Pro1’,$Profile.name=‘Pro2’),

NOT(isTrue)


)
```

Comment: Please do not delete your posts and then re-post nearly identical material.

Comment: This code is _not_ working fine in any org. When you changed this code to hide your company's identifiers, you introduced a number of errors that make it harder for the community to help you: you added smart quotes, which aren't valid; you have incorrect parentheses on the third line that cause that `OR()` to make no sense; and you have an apparent reference to a standard field `isTrue` that does not exist and whose name adds more confusion. The best thing you can do on SFSE is to create a _minimum viable reproduction_ of a _specific problem_ you need help with. See [ask] for more.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if you format your validation rule formula more like this, you might be able to follow it better:

```
AND(
   OR(
      TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Status)) = 'Esc',
      TEXT(PRIORVALUE(Status)) = 'Pending'
   ),
   NOT(ISNEW()),
   OR(
      $Profile.name = 'Pro1',
      $Profile.name = 'Pro2'
   ),
   NOT(isTrue)
)
```

---

Secondly, here is the documentation for Salesforce *Formula Operators and Functions*: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/customize_functions.htm

---

`AND(logical1,logical2,...)`: Checks whether all arguments are true and returns TRUE if all arguments are true

`OR(logical1,logical2,...)`: Checks whether any of the arguments are true and returns TRUE or FALSE. Returns FALSE only if all arguments are false

`NOT(logical)`: Changes FALSE to TRUE or TRUE to FALSE

`TEXT(value)`: Converts a value to text using standard display format

`PRIORVALUE(field)`: Returns the previous value for the field

`ISNEW()`: Checks if the record is new, and returns TRUE if it is new. Otherwise, returns FALSE

---

So walking through it slowly, piece by piece, you can see that the `AND` that is wrapping everything else is checking for four conditions:

- When this record is created or updated, it checks the `PRIORVALUE` of the *Status* field - what it was **before** the record was updated - and converts it to `TEXT`.  If the value was 'Esc' `OR` 'Pending', then that first check is TRUE.
- If the record was just created, `ISNEW()` is TRUE; therefore `NOT(ISNEW())` would be FALSE.  So in order for that second check to be TRUE, this record has to have been an existing record that was updated, not a newly created record.
- Yes `$Profile.Name` checks for the name of the Profile (not the name of the user) associated to the current user.  So if the current user's Profile name is either 'Pro1 `or 'Pro2`, then that third check is TRUE.
- I am assuming that `isTrue` is a Boolean field on this record.  If that is the case, and the value of that field is FALSE, then `NOT(isTrue)` would evaluate to TRUE.

So if all four of those checks evaluated to TRUE, which would make the overarching `AND` evaluate to TRUE, then this validation rule would display the message from the Error Message box, and it would not allow the record to be saved.

Answer (score 0):

This validation rule will prevent users with Pro1 or Pro2 profiles from editing a record if the status of the record is set to Esc or Pending. The $ variable (e.g. $User and $Profile) retrieves the values of the currently logged in user. They are called [Global Variables](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.dev_understanding_global_variables.htm&type=5), and can be used in a large array of contexts.